# Extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and its degree

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

My professor said the following:

> Suppose I know that $\sqrt[3]{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and
>   the two other conjugates of $\sqrt[3]{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ are not
>   real hence also not contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. One
>   immediately deduces that the degree of
>   $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $9$.

Everything is obvious to me here except how it follows that degree is 9.

I have considered the following tower: $\mathbb{Q}\leq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\leq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$. I know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})]\leq 3$ but since $\sqrt[3]{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ then it cannot be $1$. How it follows that it cannot be $2$?

Can anyone show this in clear way, please?

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt[3]{3}\notin \mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $[\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{2}) : \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})]$ is equal to $2$, then the minimal polynomial $m(X) \in \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})[X]$ of $\sqrt[3]{3}$ over $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ will have to be of degree two.

Is this possible? We know that $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is a root of the polynomial $X^3 - 3 \in \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})[X]$. So its minimal polynomial $m(X)$ must divide $X^3 - 3$.

If $m(X)$ is of degree $2$, then there are two possibilities: either $$m(X) = (X -  \sqrt[3]{3})(X - \sqrt[3]{3}e^{2\pi i / 3}),$$ or $$m(X) = (X -  \sqrt[3]{3})(X - \sqrt[3]{3}e^{4\pi i / 3}).$$ However, if you expand out these polynomials, you'll see that the coefficients are non-real, and hence are not actually elements of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: You mean $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})]$?

Comment: Yes, corrected now!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! +1